# AJAX response with TD tags replacing table row is placed nasty in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, html-table

I am trying to use [editInPlace](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/) JavaScript code with Python & Django on Google App Engine.
After editing the row of the table:

```
<table>
  <tr id="editme" class="editme">
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Details</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="editme" class="editme">
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Details</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="editme" class="editme">
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Details</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Which looks like this:

```
 ___ ___ ___
|___|___|___|
|___|___|___|
|___|___|___|
```

I maid that editInPlace JavaScript would save original string like "`<td>Date</td><td>Description</td><td>Details</td>`" by replacing it with striped string without `<td>` (ex. "Date Description Details") placing the string in to the `<td colspan="3"><form>...</form></td>` for editor to edit.

So here I prepared that the Http Response after submitting a new value would also be imitating 3 cols, I mean would have `<td></td>` tags (ex. "`<td>ResponseDate</td><td>ResponseDescription</td><td>ResponseDetails</td>`") to be placed in between `<tr></tr>` tags.

But the problem is such that after AJAX replacing values without refreshing hole page, gives me nasty table.
All the row in Chrome v12 is like moved a side and starts filling from the second col:

```
 ___ ___ ___
|___|___|___|___
 ___|___|___|___|
|___|___|___|
```

Comment: I'm getting this exact problem, it looks like it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Can you show , how you put in edited row ? (script(

Comment: If you are using things like `document.getElementById('tr_id').innerHTML = '<td>Cell 1</td>';`, it could cause it. Try `appendChild` or `insertBefore` if you are.

Comment: Can you put the generated HTML into a service like JSFiddle so we can see the table's code?

Comment: Doesn't happen in a very basic example in Chrome v13. Have you tried later versions? How are you inserting the result into your table?

Comment: Not sure how you are editing the entire row, but it would seem to make sense to just edit the cells and that would fix the problem of replacing the row. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Qm6cf/4/

Comment: There is a bug here. I am having the exact same problem. The table is sound, even copying the HTML via the developer tools checks out in a separate html file. I am using a TR as a partial container to replace all the TDs.

Answer (score 3):

Please use Chrome Developer Tools to inspect the affected row after it has been edited (and displayed in the wrong way) - right-click on any cell and select "Inspect Element" in the popup menu. The DevTools window will show up, and you will be able to examine (in the Elements panel) whether the final DOM is correct. If it is, then it's a Chrome/WebKit bug.

Comment: Attached is a screenshot of the rendered dom plus what is shown in the inspector. HTML is correct and identical to the next row.

www.richardson.co.nz/chrome_error.png

Comment: Unless you have some specially weird CSS style for the first row (tr:first-child or similar), then it is a WebKit reflow bug. Reproducing this issue in Safari will turn it in a surefire WebKit bug, not Chrome-specific.You can report it in the WebKit bug tracker at https://bugs.webkit.org/enter_bug.cgi (you'll have to quickly register first.)

Comment: So this bug has been transient, I can now no longer recreate after a reboot. The copy of chrome that it manifested itself on had been open for around 100+ hours.

Comment: Glad to hear! Now that a new Stable version has been released, feel free to give it a try and see if the issue is also not present there.

Comment: I have tried the reboot and clearing of the cache. No joy for me. I am using Chrome 19 and am now expecting other poor souls to find this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary of my problem**

After sometime debugging my issue i found my problem was caused by the following situation.

A class with a style `content: ""` being applied to a target TR prior to an ajax call which would replace the TDs with a fresh set of TDs, then, after removing that class I had the same problem as the OP; The end result was the shifting of the TDs to the right. The HTML on inspection was sound.

**In detail this is what I had.**

- I had a TR which was my targetId container.
- I had a TD with an ajax link that then returned a set of TDs to replace the old set within the targetId TR.
- I am using jquery ajax and prior to the call I applied a class to the targetId TR, the class of [**which can be found in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813853/511438) and contains the `content: ""` style.
- After the ajax call completes, removing that class.

**This is what I ended up doing.**

The ajax masking class I was using for the targetId, I replaced with a new class that just did some opacity. I kept the ajax masking class for the sender control.

**Relating to the OP's problem**

I downloaded and searched the "jquery-editinplace" the OP uses but could not find a `content` style being applied. Maybe someone with good search tools may find it. As stated in the comments above, the problem disappeared when chrome upgraded. This is my case of it remaining because of something possibly related.

*I have not made a fiddle of this situation as I had trouble creating an ajax scenario. I would have liked to to prove it is a chrome bug and to submit it to Google.*

*Feel free to comment if something is unclear and I will update my answer accordingly.*

Answer (score -1):

To me, use same Id on multiple <tr> seems awkward.

It might cause some weird behavior.

Keep your unique Id per DOM.

Also I would use

```
<div>
```

Instead of tables

because with <div>, you can get more control with CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <div class="editme">
    <div>Date</div>
    <div>Description</div>
    <div>Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="editme">
    <div>Date</div>
    <div>Description</div>
    <div>Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="editme">
    <div>Date</div>
    <div>Description</div>
    <div>Details</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.editme { clear:both; }
.editme div { float:left; }
```

So after changing your HTML and CSS like this

you can simply replace those three divs

with a single DIV with FORM

[Here is an example of DIV version](http://jsfiddle.net/inspired_jw/5UyNP/)

Comment: It's most definitely tabular data, hence the table layout.